# What do these prior distributions mean?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian

Suppose we have a prior distribution of $$\pi_1(\theta)=k\theta^{k-1},$$ and we have another of $$\pi_2(\theta)=k(1-\theta)^{k-1}.$$ Intuitively, what do the two different distributions mean / represent?

I understand that the summarise the beliefs of the tester before and after the test, but I don't understand specifically what these ones mean. Are they not both very much the same, since if $\theta\in(0,1)$, then so is $(1-\theta)$, and the only "difference" is that one is analogous to probability of throwing heads, while the other is analogous to throwing tails - by symmetry aren't both these prior distributions "the same"?

I'd like to understand what $k$ and $\theta$ represent.

---

Note: both have $\theta\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Same question is answered on Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/281956/16592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second function you mention leaves no doubt that you're talking about probability density functions and not about cumulative probability distribution functions.

The first one concentrates probability near $1$ and puts little near $0$. The pair does have just the kind of symmetry that you mention.

The first one is the probability density of the maximum of $k$ independent observations that are uniformly distributed in the interval from $0$ to $1$.

The second one is the probability density of the minimum of those observations.

Comment: What if $k$ was not an integer? Then there cannot be $k$ observations - is there any other way of viewing the density function then? Also, yes I was talking about pdfs - I should have made that clear in the question. If it helps, the likelihood is $$f(\vec x|\theta)=\left(\prod_{i=1}^n {{m}\choose x_i}\right)\theta^{\sum x_i}(1-\theta)^{nm-\sum x_i}$$ - i.e. there are $m$ Bernoulli random variables $X_i$.

Comment: Same question is answered on Cross Validated: stats.stackexchange.com/a/281956/16592

Comment: @JohnK.Kruschke Yes, I asked it there after asking it here since it didn't get many views here, and it seemed like it was better suited there. Interestingly, there is a different answer there.